# Function of 吧 in 循环吧代码

Tags: meaning, usage

In this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code) for learning loops in JavaScript by Mozilla Developer Network the title "Looping code" is translated as 循环吧代码. What is the meaning/function of 吧 here?

Comment: Exclamation. Used after verbs in exclamatory sentences. 循环吧！代码！Start Looping! Code!

Comment: 循环吧！代码！is more like: " 'Let's loop' code"

Comment: I think 循环代码 is just fine. 循环吧代码 looks odd.

Comment: Is it a typo? The Taiwan Chinese version of the page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/%E5%BE%AA%E7%92%B0%E4%BB%A3%E7%A2%BC) doesn't have「吧」.

Comment: @Tang It's not-so-good translation from English (Chinese version mentioned in question is more cute). But OP is talking about usage of 吧, not how to translate English, so I think my answer is OK.

Comment: More close translation would be 循环代码, just compound noun, no cuteness, just like the original English text.

Comment: @神秘德里克 I think there is enough in your comments to make an answer. If I understood correctly you are saying that as a native speaker 循环吧代码 looks like an exclamation, but in this context it looks odd or unnecessary so it could also be a typo

Comment: The Chinese on that page is not that good.

Comment: Chinese version of MDN articles are basically translated by machine, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit more like **Imperative Mood (祈qi2使shi3句ju4)** for me.

*sorry I don't know how to type the tone mark

For example,

1. 來**吧**！我準備好了！
   (Come on! I'm ready!)
2. 上**吧**！皮卡丘！
   (Go fight! Pikachu!)
3. 奔跑**吧**！男孩！(Run! boys!)
4. 好好享受**吧**！(Enjoy yourself!)

Answer (score 1):

This is an exclamatory sentence. (It lakes exclamation mark 循环吧！代码 )

It means "代码，循环吧！"

It seems like that:

[滚蛋吧！肿瘤君](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BB%9A%E8%9B%8B%E5%90%A7%EF%BC%81%E8%82%BF%E7%98%A4%E5%90%9B)

[翻滚吧！阿信](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BF%BB%E6%BB%BE%E5%90%A7%EF%BC%81%E9%98%BF%E4%BF%A1)